# XAML Warning "The resource could not be resolved"

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using `DynamicResources` in WPF, I have made a `button style` in `app.xaml`. Below is the definition:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="InteractionButtonStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
            </Style>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StyleBasedForegroundColor" Color="White"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StyleBasedBackgroundColor" Color="Black" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource StyleBasedBackgroundColor}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource StyleBasedForegroundColor}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now when I use this style in a page:

```
<Button Grid.Row="3"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Click="RegisterNew_Clicked"
        Style="{StaticResource InteractionButtonStyle}"
        Visibility="{Binding ShowRegisterVeteranOption, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Viewbox  Height="20"
                  Width="20">
            <Path Data="M9.6110058,5.399L11.650064,5.399 11.650064,9.6789093 15.929999,9.6789093 15.929999,11.717999 11.650064,11.717999 11.650064,15.998 9.6110058,15.998 9.6110058,11.717999 5.3309995,11.717999 5.3309995,9.6789093 9.6110058,9.6789093z M10.66645,1.6420071C5.6808301,1.6420071 1.6404767,5.6823504 1.6404767,10.66655 1.6404767,15.650881 5.6808301,19.691223 10.66645,19.691223 15.64948,19.691223 19.689723,15.650881 19.689723,10.66655 19.689723,5.6823504 15.64948,1.6420071 10.66645,1.6420071z M10.66645,0C16.546567,0 21.333001,4.785153 21.333001,10.66655 21.333001,16.548068 16.546567,21.333 10.66645,21.333 4.7836227,21.333 0,16.548068 0,10.66655 0,4.785153 4.7836227,0 10.66645,0z"
                  Fill="{DynamicResource StyleBasedForegroundColor}" />
        </Viewbox>
        <TextBlock Text="Register"
                   Margin="10,0,0,0"
                   Foreground="{DynamicResource StyleBasedForegroundColor}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Although, things work when the app is running, I get this annoying warning:

> The resource "StyleBasedForegroundColor" could not be resolved.

I looked up other questions, but could not find a way that doesn't involve `themes.xaml` or `ResourceDictionary`

Comment: Move the (2) 'SolidColorBrushes' outside of the 'Style'  And move them before the `style` as the order matters.

Comment: @Jeff The two `SolidColorBrushes` are actually a part of the style. Not my entire app. It's a style resource.

Comment: Happens to me all the time.. I just delete bin/obj, rebuild, restart visual studio.. If it still happens, i close only my resource dictionaries.. Keeping them open returns error. If nothing helps, i just curse VS and move on with my task.

Comment: @iam.Carrot I realize that are a part of a style.  In order to eliminate the warning, they need to be removed from the style.  There appears to be no reason they are a style resource.  Alternatively, create an app level resource and use this for both locations - in the style and when not in a style.